# Add customize criteria in Drupal views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i have created a views wherein i need to list the nodes based on package criteria for content type.. These packages are entered in the content type as an text field and the possible values are Platinum, Gold and Silver..... The nodes listed should be based on package values entered in the content types higher package should appear first... which in my case would be Platinum,, Gold and Silver...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your field configuration, set the allowed values as key|label. This will allow you to store a different value against the package then what is shown to user i.e. Platinum can be stored as 'a', Gold can be stored as 'b' etc. In views, add a sort criteria to sort by the field.

Comment: Hey Abhijit, Thanx for the input but i don't see the option for set key|label? where that? i m using drupal 6

Comment: hope you are not talking about the CCK field configuration and this option is on views creation screen?

Comment: No, he means in the CCK field configuration for _Allowed values_.  This will work

Comment: But won't will that become a bottleneck if tomorrow some more new value in added?

Comment: If you want to give the user freedom to enter any value, then I think it will be more difficult. How will views know which value should come before which? But, if the admin/editor takes care of the possible values, then it's not a bottleneck, I guess.

Comment: furthermore it will have save all the existing content as well... to apply that changes?